# Why shutdown button only works when HDMI monitor is connected

Tags: power-management, shutdown, hdmi, etc

It sounds weird, but I configured my Ubuntu 18.04-4 LTS to shutdown immediately when I press the power button but it works fine ONLY when the HDMI monitor is connected.

If I disconnect the monitor (I usually use this PC without a monitor), the power button doesn't work anymore. As soon as I connect again the monitor, the system automatically shuts off.

It seems like he looks for the monitor before to power off.

Why this happen and how can I solve it?
I need to power off the computer when I press the power button and I can't connect the monitor since I use this computer by remotely connecting to it.

Comment: Don't unplug the monitor until after you pressed the power button on the computer. You can press the power button on the monitor though and the computer will still think it is connected for a minute or so

Comment: as I said, the computer is used without its monitor, so, unfortunately, I can't connect the monitor.